# Java: counting int values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array consisting of numbers from 0 to 10. For example,

```
1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 1, 9
```

And I want to count the number of occurrences of each number from 0 to 10 in the array. Something like this (a simulation of the output):

```
number | occurrence
0        0
1        2
2        0
3        2
4        0
5        2
6        0
7        2
8        0
9        1
10       0
```

EDIT: This is a high school assignment: Write a program that repeatedly prompts the user to supply scores (out of 10) on a test. The program should continue to ask the user for marks until a negative value is supplied. Any values greater than ten should be ignored. Once the program has read all the scores, it should produce a table with the following headings (and automatically fill in the rest of the table):
Score       # of Occurrences
The program should then calculate the mean score, rounded to one decimal place.
My code in response to this question:

```
public static int[] resize(int[] a) {   
    int[] expandedArray = new int[a.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        expandedArray[i] = a[i];
    }
    return expandedArray;   
}

public static void main (String[]args) {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean positive = true;
    int count = 0;
    int[] originArray = new int[0];

    for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int i = 0; positive; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a score: ");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The input is recorded: " + input);


        if (input < 0) {
            positive = false;
            System.out.println("The input is negative.");

        }else if (input > 10){
            System.out.println("///INVALID///: Must be out of 10!");
        } else {

            System.out.println("count: " + count);

            originArray = resize(originArray);
            System.out.println("originArray resized");

            originArray[count] = input;

            System.out.println("The index = count = " + count +" would be assigned input: " + input);

            for (int j = 0; j <= count; j++) {
                System.out.println(j + ": " + originArray[j]);
            }
            count++;
            System.out.println("count++: " + count);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Program has stopped taking inputs. Outputting results:");
    System.out.println("   Score   | Occurrences ");
    }
```

Comment: "_I want to ..._" So, what's the problem?

Comment: If you have tried something, share with us and explain why it did not work.

Comment: Unclear how you want the output. `HashMap` or `int[]` or other?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. try to ask for explicit things. like: how can i do X? also tell us why and where you are struggeling. this platform is not for simply solving your problems, but helping you to understand how to approach the problem yourself.

Comment: I am a student programmer and I do not know how to approach this problem.

Comment: I want to learn how to scan the indexes of the array and recognize them as a specific integer. If it is a 10, then the integer 10 would occur once (more).

Comment: @Shashwat I have not. I have researched many approaches and HashMap seemed to occur frequently. I have attempted this approach myself, but to no avail.

Comment: @Shashwat Speed doesn't matter. If looping through twice would be able to identify and count the int in the array, then there is no problem. But I don't know how to do this either...

Comment: You seem to think that if you don't know how to do something you can't learn it. You keep saying "I don't know how to do that", but that is a broad statement. Go read up on the process in question and explain **specifically** what **exact** step is confusing to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are given the input array, following code will produce the results for you in the counts array.

```
int [] counts = new int[11];
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    counts[input[i]]++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. From what I can understand, the indexes of the count array represent the number occurring. The index will be the number that counts occurrence. Yes?

Comment: @Shashwat I had made a failsafe for the inputs to the array so that none are bigger than 10.

Comment: True, the index 0 of counts shows the count of number 0 in the input and so on. you can change the count array length from 11 to whatever number depending on you max number.